# Что означает этот параметр?

Tags: erlang

Есть строка

```
{"/:order_id/payments/[:payment_id]", order_payments_handler, []}
```

От клиента идет обращение по данному url и выполняется какое то действие. Интересует что такое [:payment_id], почему в квадратных скобках и что сюда должно быть передано?

Answer (score 0):

Это так называемый binding

Например Вам необходимо сделать rest сервис который делает запись данных о книге в книжном магазине, вы создаёте запись в бд и получаете, какой-то идентификатор, например 123321.

Согласно протокола Вам необходимо получить данные о книге по идентификатору через ссылку

http://localhost:8080/api/books/123321

Так вот в данном случае 123321 и есть этот binding

Его можно получить через функцию

cowboy_req:binding(id, Req)

Где id- атом который вы указали в dispatch’e

/api/books/[:id]

Детальнее в описании
https://ninenines.eu/docs/en/cowboy/2.1/guide/req/